# In Mocktio unit test, is it possible to test side effect of a method on a mocked input argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have method in a java class (call it routing) that takes an input argument of certain Interface (call it Rules) and calls the register method on that input argument with some local variable and returns void.

I want to unit test the routing method but I don't want to pass a real implementation of Rules interface.

I want to pass a mock Rules as parameter to routing method call.
e.g.

```
@Mock
Rules rules; //mocked interface

@Test
void test1() {
   testCase = new MyClass();
   testcase.routing(Rules);  // returns void
}
```

Is is possible to have some state in the mocked rules object and verify that its state changes after my routing method is called?

I know one option is to have a simple implementation of the Rules interface and have full control over it but I wanted to know if Mockito has anything out of the box for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that, but this will make the test an integration test, not unit test. Like this you would be testing not only `MyClass`, but `Rules` as well. If you need an integration test, then write an integration test and it would be better to use real instances/implementations for this.

You should verify the interactions with the mock:

```
@Mock
Rules rules;

@Test
void test1() {
   MyClass testCase = new MyClass();
   testcase.routing(rules);

   verify(rules, times(2)).someMethod();
   //verifies 2 interactions with someMethod()

   verify(rules).anotherMethod("something");
   //verifies 1 invocation of anotherMethod() with parameter value `something`

   verify(rules, never()).lastMethod(any());
   //verifies no invocations lastMethod() regardless of parameter value
}
```